# What can I do to to store/save a list of Class on Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-8.1

I have a small Project. I want to write a Windows Phone Application which stores a List of Items. 
I tried to save the list as a XML document using Linq, that worked fine on a PC but i got a problem with the

```
XDoc.Save();
```

On PC I could use a String but on Windows Phone I need a Stream or a XML(Text) Writer but I have no idea how I can do this.
I tried to save a .txt file too, I always get the same exception and have no idea why.

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

If someone knows a way to store the List items. Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

To save to a file under Windows Phone 8.1 you have to use a StorageFile object. Here is an example:

```
      using System.IO;  // needed for OpenStreamForWriteAsync()
      ....

      StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("myfile.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
      using (Stream stream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
      {
          //try XDoc.Save(stream);
      }
```

to read a file:

```
        StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(FILENAME);
        using (Stream stream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            var XDoc = System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(stream); 
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for that. But what what should i use for reading the XML?
XDoc.Load(storageFile.???)